# Bash script with mv won't work

Tags: bash, command, mv

I've written the following bash script:

```
alias uploadToCloud='
say "Which file would you like me to upload, $name?"
echo "File?"
read $file
mv $file ~/Dropbox
say "It will be online soon."
echo "The file will be online soon."
'
```

But when running it I get the following output:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I am really not sure of what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a function instead of alias in your profile file. Something like this -

```
uploadToCloud() {
    echo "which file"
    read file
    mv "$file" ~/Dropbox
}
```

A function should be used when you need to do something more complex. Your requirement is a perfect example of a function because it is too complex for an alias.

An alias should be used for tasks that effectively change the default options of a command.

Comment: +1 function is indeed much better than alias in this situation. also pointed out the problem on "read" line.

Comment: @Kent Thanks Kent. I didn't even see the problem in `read line`. I just saw `alias` being used for something like that so suggested `function`. :)

Comment: I'll go with the +1 for fixing the `read file` (instead of `read $file`) problem. I'm not convinced anyone would execute the code often enough to warrant making it an alias or function — in my ecosystem, it would be a shell script (and would take file names by argument, at least as the primary interface).  However, I'm an old fuddy-duddy on such issues — modern style seems to be to load as much as possible into memory so as to save a few milliseconds on those rare occasions when something is needed.